# How to determine what font supports Lowercase on iOS?

Tags: ios, fonts, uifont

I use custom fonts in the app. The number of fonts is not limited. Some fonts do not have lowercase support, but I need to enable/disable the lowercase/uppercase button in the UI. How can I determine if the font supports lowercase and uppercase, or only one of the modes?

For example: Horizon and Impact Label fonts

Comment: When you say "do not have lowercase support," in what sense? They have no glyph for `a`, or they use the same glyph for `a` as `A`, or some other sense? "Lowercase" is a very Latin alphabet distinction, so what do you expect out of fonts that do not include Latin glyphs? Do you have specific iOS-default fonts for which you would like to return "yes" and other specific iOS-default fonts for which you would like to return "no?"

Comment: In my experience the lower case glyph is usually the same as upper case.  For example Bebas Neue the lower case characters are uppercase. I will say there are metrics inside the glyph that might be different but the glyph appears in uppercase.

Comment: Bebas Neue is not an iOS-default font. So you're installing this font yourself? Don't you know the configuration of fonts that you install yourself? But as you say, Bebas Neue does seem to have lowercase support, in that it has a glyph for `a` (glyph 140). It just happen to look visually like the glyph for `A` (glyph 4). That's not "doesn't have lowercase support." I don't see any metadata in the Bebas Neue Regular TTF file that claims anything different. There's no reliable way to tell the difference between "lowercase but looks like uppercase" and "lowercase and looks like lowercase."

Comment: But thank you so much for introducing me to Bebas Neue which is the first font I've encountered with an explicit glyph for for Bitcoin (₿; I want to see how StackOverflow renders that).

Comment: @RobNapier Yes, I have problems with not default fonts for iOS. In our application, users can install custom fonts and we have a lowercase / uppercase button, and we need to disable this button if lowercase and uppercase look the same. For example, there are also Horizon and Impact Label fonts.